# can i download the same torrent file in different machines and then merge them together by connecting the computers with an Ethernet cable?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bittorrent

My situation is that I am in a college and my college has set an upper limit of download speed per machine at 2mb/s. i.e I can download a file at 2Mb/s in my machine, at the same time my buddy can download another file at 2Mb/s in his machine.

Can I download the same torrent file in different machines, and then merge them together by connecting the two computers with an ethernet cable? If possible I would like to know how to do that with single torrent files, since I guess if the torrent has multiple files then it really wouldn't be a question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's really no different from a regular download.

If both clients have "Local Peer Discovery" enabled, they'll soon connect to each other over LAN as regular peers and will provide the missing parts.

Comment: Do they know they are close by, and negotiate to avoid duplicate work?

Comment: They know they're close by, but I _think_ the "duplicate work" avoidance is already somewhat implied in regular BitTorrent piece selection algorithms already... Needs more research.